# CartesianIndices from start and end tuples

Tags: julia

I want to construct `CartesianIndices` using start and end tuples. For example, I want to construct `CartesianIndices((2:4, 3:5))` given `start = (2,3)` and `end = (4,5)`.

`CartesianIndices` provides no constructor for this. Is there an easy alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
julia> CartesianIndices(UnitRange.((2,3), (4,5))) |> collect
3×3 Matrix{CartesianIndex{2}}:
 CartesianIndex(2, 3)  CartesianIndex(2, 4)  CartesianIndex(2, 5)
 CartesianIndex(3, 3)  CartesianIndex(3, 4)  CartesianIndex(3, 5)
 CartesianIndex(4, 3)  CartesianIndex(4, 4)  CartesianIndex(4, 5)
```